# How can I build a Vega tooltip that dynamically populates the available series names?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

The Vega gallery has a nice [example](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_multi_line_pivot_tooltip.html) showing a "cursor" based tooltip which is populated acccording the values of each of the series that are being plotted.

It uses this code to construct the tooltip

```
 "tooltip": [
          {"field": "AAPL", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "AMZN", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "GOOG", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "IBM", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "MSFT", "type": "quantitative"}
        ]
```

However, in our application we are dynamically inserting data and the set of series names is not known at the time we construct the chart specification.  Is there any way to *dynamically* construct this tooltip based on filtering/transforming the values found in the data?  What I'm looking for is something like this C# pseudocode...

```
tooltip = data.GroupBy(datapoint =>datapoint.SeriesName)
              .Select(series => new { 
                                      MaxValue=series.Max(datapoint=>datapoint.Y),
                                      Name=series.SeriesName
                                    }
              .OrderByDescending(s=>s.MaxValue) // "nice to have" but optional 
              .Select(s=>s.Name)
              .ToArray().
```

I.e in the ideal world we'd not only figure out the names of the series from the data but also order them sensibly according to the how the series appear in the chart.   In fact it would be even better to dynamically change the ordering of the tooltip rows as the cursor is moved over different regions of the chart.